# jQuery plugin looping through siblings

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, javascript-namespaces

I'm new to writing jQuery plug-ins so I'm a little unsure how to do this.  The plug-in is to display labels as tips inside text and password inputs.  It's kind of simple - on element focus, the label is hidden.  Also on document load it checks to see if the browser has auto-completed any field forms - if so, the label is hidden.  The problem I am having is autocomplete of other fields.  To solve this, I'm trying to bind a function to the onblur and keyup events of the element to loop through other form elements and work out whether they've been autocompleted.

Here is the annotated code.

```
(function( $ ){
  $.fn.innerLabels = function( ) {
    return this.each(function() {        
    var $this = $(this);
// Initialise all form elements with class
    $this.each(function() {
    var lngth = $(this).val().length;
    if(lngth > 0){
        $(this).parent().children('label').hide();
    }else{
        $(this).parent().children('label').show();
    };
    });
// onfocus event - clears label
    $this.focus(function() {
    $this.parent().children('label').hide();
    });
// onblur/keyup event re-enstates label if length of value is zero or hides if autocompleted.
    $this.bind("blur keyup",function() {
// check all fields in case of autocomplete <- this is the problem
    $(this).each(function() {
    var lngth = $(this).val().length;
    //alert(lngth);
    if(lngth > 0){
        $(this).parent().children('label').hide();
    }else{
        $(this).parent().children('label').show();
    };
    });
    });
    });
  };
})( jQuery );
```

It's triggered by doing this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.txtbox').innerLabels();
});
```

.txtbox is a class that I add to form text and password fields that I want to use this on.

I think it's a scope problem.  The last $(this).each is the problem.  Rather than looping through all elements with the .txtbox class, it's looping through the value of the input in which the event is taking place.  I don't want to add the class name to the plug-in because it will add extra code and make it less flexible.

Any advice on this would be appreciated.

Cheers

Greg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just by looking at your code it looks like you're trying to execute the initialization code again upon blur. Is this the case? If so, refactor that common code into a function and simply call it from your event handler:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.innerLabels = function() {
        var $self = this;
        var hideElements = function() {
            $self.each(function() {
                var lngth = $(this).val().length;
                if (lngth > 0) {
                    $(this).parent().children('label').hide();
                } else {
                    $(this).parent().children('label').show();
                };
            });  
        };

        hideElements();

        return $self.focus(function() {
            $(this).parent().children("label").hide();
        }).bind("blur keyup", hideElements);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

After some refactoring I also didn't see the need for the `.each` call (in the `return` statement), since assigning event handlers will work for every item in the set of matched elements.

Hope that's what you were after.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for - thank you!  I thought it needed some refactoring but I didn't think of just calling one function. I guess that's what happens when you start on something and then tack more on to it.  Originally it was just using `.focus()` and `blur()` but since we're using `keyup()` there's no need to use `.focus()`
The return statement was just because I was following a jQuery plug-in tutorial and I didn't really know what I was doing! :)

Comment: @shadylane: No problem! Glad I could help. Sometimes it just takes a second pair of eyes.

Answer (score 0):

In jquery you can select the siblings by using the next() function

```
$(this).next()
```

will select the next one.

[More on next()](http://docs.jquery.com/JQuery_1.2_Roadmap)

Comment: Thanks, but that wasn't quite what I was looking for.  The text inputs are nested in some other markup.  On the 'keyup()' or 'blur()' events I wanted the function to check all the form elements to see if any had been autocompleted.  Check Andrew Whitaker's response below.